# Adding custom TensorFlow OP

Tags: c++, tensorflow, ubuntu, cuda, nvcc

I am trying to use the Tensorflow implementation of compact bilinear pooling by [ronghanghu](https://github.com/ronghanghu/tensorflow_compact_bilinear_pooling) since it's used in the [implementation](https://github.com/pengzhou1108/RGB-N) of the **"Learning Rich Features for Image Manipulation Detection"** paper. [ronghanghu](https://github.com/ronghanghu/tensorflow_compact_bilinear_pooling) uses TensorFlow version 1.12.0 with CUDA 8.0 and g++ 5.4.0 to build `sequential_batch_fft.so`. However, they do say we can rebuild the `sequential_batch_fft.so` using a different version of Tensorflow (in my case 2.4.0) with a different compiler (g++ 7.5.0) and a different CUDA version (11.0). When I try to build `sequential_batch_fft.so` using the commands in `compile.sh` below

```
TF_INC=$(python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.sysconfig.get_include())')
TF_LIB=$(python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.sysconfig.get_lib())')

# Use 0 if the TensorFlow binary is built with GCC 4.x
# see https://docs.computecanada.ca/wiki/GCC_C%2B%2B_Dual_ABI for details
USE_CXX11_ABI=0

nvcc -std=c++11 -c -o sequential_batch_fft_kernel.cu.o \
sequential_batch_fft_kernel.cu.cc \
-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=$USE_CXX11_ABI -DNDEBUG \
-L$TF_LIB -ltensorflow_framework \
-I $TF_INC -D GOOGLE_CUDA=1 -x cu -Xcompiler -fPIC

g++ -std=c++11 -shared -o ./build/sequential_batch_fft.so \
sequential_batch_fft_kernel.cu.o \
sequential_batch_fft.cc \
-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=$USE_CXX11_ABI -DNDEBUG \
-L$TF_LIB -ltensorflow_framework \
-I $TF_INC -fPIC \
-lcudart -lcufft -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64

rm -rf sequential_batch_fft_kernel.cu.o
```

the only output I get in the terminal is this.
[image: compile.sh output]

The problem is nothing else happens beyond that. No errors reported and it doesn't end the build. Left it for hours and still nothing. I am completely clueless as to why this is. I later decided to try doing one of the examples provided by TensorFlow on [adding_an_op](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.1/tensorflow/examples/adding_an_op) and I got the same result. What could be the problem here? It's really confusing for me because there are no errors just a never-ending program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with the tensorflow_framework.so. Was able to fix this by creating a symbolic link `ln -s libtensorflow_framework.so.2 libtensorflow_framework.so` in ../site-packages/tensorflow. Also, I think my project path was not suitable as it contains spaces. Not so sure about this one but when I used TensorFlow installed on a path with no spaces everything worked fine.